# Change complex text based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have some code that looks vaguely like this:

```html
What is your experience level?<br>
<select>
    <option value="1">Inexperienced</option>
    <option value="2">Some experience</option>
    <option value="3">Expert</option>
<select>

<div> [custom text would go here] </div>
```

I'd like the custom text in the div to automatically populate based on the dropdown choice.  I've seen a few JavaScript solutions to this, but the text is always simple, and the javascript might include:

```html
myarr[1]="custom text #1"
myarr[2]="custom text #2"
```

But the text I want filled in would be more complex and would include quotes, which would certainly break that javascript, e.g.:

```html
custom_text[1]:
Please contact John Novice<br>
<div class="pushbutton"><a href="mailto:john.novice@example.com">john.novice@example.com</a></div>
<div class="pushbutton"><a href="tel:+18005559994">800-555-9994</a></div>

custom_text[2]:
Please contact Jane Intermediate<br>
<div class="pushbutton"><a href="mailto:jane.intermediate@example.com">jane.intermediate@example.com</a></div>
<div class="pushbutton"><a href="tel:+18005559995">800-555-9995</a></div>
```

Is something like this possible?  FWIW, I'm a javascript neophyte, so be gentle.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess that the text in the array would include HTML tags?

Comment: You can have whatever text (even markup and quotes) stored in a javascript variable.  You just need to escape/unescape them properly when you store/inject them.

Comment: Jeez, you'd think I'd have thought of that.  Thanks for the good info!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is escape the quotes with a backslash. For example:

```
var str = "Please contact John Novice<br><div class=\"pushbutton\"><a href=\"mailto:john.novice@example.com\">john.novice@example.com</a></div><div class=\"pushbutton\"><a href=\"tel:+18005559994\">800-555-9994</a></div>";
```

Comment: or use single quotes for element attributes or single quotes around the whole string ... JS treats `'` and `"` equally (unlike C*)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `innerHTML` of the Div. Also, you need to ensure that the variable can hold the HTML content and assign an `onchange` event handler which would be triggered whenever the selected option in dropdown is changed.

```
var custom_text =  'Please contact John Novice<br> \
<div class="pushbutton"><a \ href="mailto:john.novice@example.com">john.novice@example.com</a></div> \
<div class="pushbutton"><a href="tel:+18005559994">800-555-9994</a></div>';

document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = custom_text;
```

**Complete Code:**

```js
var custom_text =  'Please contact John Novice<br> \
<div class="pushbutton"><a \ href="mailto:john.novice@example.com">john.novice@example.com</a></div> \
<div class="pushbutton"><a href="tel:+18005559994">800-555-9994</a></div>';


function addContent(){
document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML = custom_text;
}
```

```html
What is your experience level?<br>
<select onchange="addContent()">
    <option value="1">Inexperienced</option>
    <option value="2">Some experience</option>
    <option value="3">Expert</option>
<select>

<div id="divContent">  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand your question well but i try guess that you are finding something like this :

jQuery

```js
var tempText = "Please contact Jane Intermediate<br><div class='pushbutton'><a href='mailto:jane.intermediate@example.com'>jane.intermediate@example.com</a></div><div class='pushbutton'><a href='tel:+18005559995'>800-555-9995</a></div>";
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#slct").on("change", function (){
    $("#selectResult").html(tempText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
What is your experience level?<br>
<select id="slct">
    <option value="1">Inexperienced</option>
    <option value="2">Some experience</option>
    <option value="3">Expert</option>
<select>
<div id="selectResult">  </div>
```

Pure Js :

```js
var tempText1 = "Please contact Jane begginer<br><div class='pushbutton'><a href='mailto:jane.intermediate@example.com'>jane.intermediate@example.com</a></div><div class='pushbutton'><a href='tel:+18005559995'>800-555-9995</a></div>";
var tempText2 = "Please contact Jane Intermediate<br><div class='pushbutton'><a href='mailto:jane.intermediate@example.com'>jane.intermediate@example.com</a></div><div class='pushbutton'><a href='tel:+18005559995'>800-555-9995</a></div>";
var tempText3 = "Please contact Jane advance<br><div class='pushbutton'><a href='mailto:jane.intermediate@example.com'>jane.intermediate@example.com</a></div><div class='pushbutton'><a href='tel:+18005559995'>800-555-9995</a></div>";


//document.getElementById("slct").change = vlCng();

function vlCng() {
  var txt = "--";
  var val = document.getElementById("slct").value;
  if (val === "1")
    txt = tempText1;
  if (val === "2")
    txt = tempText2;
  if (val === "3")
    txt = tempText3;

  document.getElementById("selectResult").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
What is your experience level?<br>
<select onchange="vlCng()" id="slct">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Inexperienced</option>
        <option value="2">Some experience</option>
        <option value="3">Expert</option>
<select>
<div id="selectResult">  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use CSS and very little javascript

Firstly you add all the HTML to div's inside the "target" div, which are hidden

Using easily crafted CSS you can unhide the appropriate div when the target div has a particular class, for example. To make things **really** simple, you use the value of the option as a class for each "sub" div, and when the main div has the same class, it results in the sub div being displayed

```js
document.getElementById('selector').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('target').className = this[this.selectedIndex].value;
})
```

```css
#target>div {
    display: none;
}
#target.none>div.none {
    display: block;
}
#target.some>div.some {
    display: block;
}
#target.expert>div.expert {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<Select id="selector">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
    <option value="none">Inexperienced</option>
    <option value="some">Some Experience</option>
    <option value="expert">Expert</option>
</Select>
<div id="target">
    <div class="none">You are <b>inexperienced</b></div>
    <div class="some">You have <b>some</b> experience</div>
    <div class="expert">You are an <b>expert</b></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible.

I assume you want the data in your HTML, you can add it to the value attribute and it will be set:

```js
function change() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  
  output.innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onChange="change()">
    <option value='
    Please contact John Novice<br>
    <div class="pushbutton"><a href="mailto:john.novice@example.com">
      john.novice@example.com
    </a></div>
    <div class="pushbutton"><a href="tel:+18005559994">
        800-555-9994
    </a></div>'>
    
      Inexperienced
    
    </option>
    <option value='
    Please contact Medium<br>
    <div class="pushbutton"><a href="mailto:john.novice@example.com">
      medium@example.com
    </a></div>
    <div class="pushbutton"><a href="tel:+18005559994">
        800-555-9995
    </a></div>'>
    
      Some experience
    
    </option>
    
    <option value="3">Expert</option>
<select>

<div id="output"> [custom text would go here] </div>
```